# Subtracting last number in a colum that is not a zero

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uwVY.jpg)I have the days of the year in column A. Every day a number (Gallons of water pumped) is input into column B next to day of year. In column (C), the most recent number input into B subtracts the prior number in column B. I only want a whole number, other than a zero, to subtract the most recent prior non zero number.

Also, when the number in column C shows as a result of this formula, I would like to see 2 trailing zeros added (not a 2 place decimal).

Comment: I am sure this can be done, show some sample data of what you have, and what you want from it

Comment: Better add some sample Data & the expected output will help us to fix the  issue!!  Also be clear  that how would you find the prior Number!!

Comment: Alan, you should have added the data by **editing this question**, not add a whole new question https://superuser.com/q/1446134/534850 . Use the [edit] button (under the tags of your question) to edit this question and delete the other question.

Comment: I have edited the Question. Need some help. This suggested formula does not work  =(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(0,B:B,0)-2)-INDEX(B:B,MATCH(0,B:B,0)-1)) & "00"

Answer (score 2):

With data like:

[image]

in **C1** enter:

```
=(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(0,B:B,0)-2)-INDEX(B:B,MATCH(0,B:B,0)-1)) & "00"
```

[image]

*(this assumes that column **B** has been pre-filled with zeros)*

Comment: Ron, I do need your help. Can you figure this out for me?

Comment: Gary, Look at my edited question and example. Can you create the formular? I mistakenly said your answer was ok. It was not. I did not ask ith properly.

Comment: @Alan  I will look at the revision tomorrow,

Comment: Gary, have a chance to look at it again?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are doing,  but to return the last non-zero number in column A:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($A:$A<>0),$A:$A)
```

Comment: Reasked my question with more info and an example. Thanks for prior answer, can you take another look?

Comment: @Alan You've already accepted Gary's Student's answer.  So it seems no need for me to look at your question again.  For the part about adding two trailing non-decimal zeros, merely multiply by 100.

Comment: Ron, new to site. Gary answer did not help. Can you review my question? Reasked my question with more info and an example. Thanks for prior answer, can you take another look?

Comment: @Alan Since you've accepted Gary's answer, you should indicate to him where he has misunderstood things.  And for my part, I've answered the only two parts of your question I understand. One in my answer, and one in a comment. Perhaps if you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you'll be able to formulate a better question.